# gitinfo (xstring): tag info does not work because of "tag:" before version number

Tags: xstring, git, gitinfo

I'm making the switch from subversion to git, and I'm quite happy with the `gitinfo` package. The only thing I cannot get to work is to show a version number from the tag.

I have identified the problem: when tag a commit, the reference metadata shows "tag: 0.1". In Brent's example file it is just shown as "0.1" - the latter works, the former doesn't, see the MWE below.

Am I doing something wrong with git or is that a (fixable?) limitation of the package. I'm using git 1.9.0 on Windows if that is relevant.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gitinfo}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{gitHeadInfo.gin}
\usepackage[%
        refnames={ (HEAD, tag: 1.0, master)}
    ]{gitsetinfo}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\gitVtags
\gitVtag
\gitVtagn

\end{document}
```

**Edit**: and the definition of the Vtag commands is:

```
\newcommand{\git@vtag}[1]{%
    \def\do##1{%
        \IfDecimal{##1}{%
            \renewcommand{\gitVtag}{##1}
            \renewcommand{\gitVtags}{\space##1}
            \renewcommand{\gitVtagn}{\space##1}
            \listbreak
        }{}%
    }%
    \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{#1}%
}%
```

Comment: I'm working on `gitinfo` 2.0, which I hope will solve this problem (and a number of others).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need an alternative git-set-info routine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gitinfo}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{gitHeadInfo.gin}
\usepackage[%
        refnames={ (HEAD, tag: 1.0, master)}
     ]{mygitsetinfo}% call the new routine here
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\gitVtags
\gitVtag
\gitVtagn

\end{document}
```

The routine needs to feed `\IfDecimal` a decimal if there is one. If we have `tag: 1.0` rather than `1.0`, we need to remove the `tag:` first. The facilities of `xstring` which `gitinfo` uses to provide `\IfDecimal` also provide a command which can do this. `\StrCut` allows you to cut a string at a certain character and save the two parts in two macros. I've used `\lcut` and `\rcut` to hold these strings although we are only actually interested in the right hand part.

To allow for both `tag: 1.0` and `1.0`, I've used a nested conditional. First I cut the string and save the two parts. Then I test if `\rcut` is a decimal. If so, use that result. If not, see if the uncut argument is itself a decimal. If so, use that. If not, return nothing.

Save the following as `mygetsetinfo.sty`:

```
% mygitsetinfo.sty
% Code from gitsetinfo.sty copyright 2011 Brent Longborough (see below).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% The file mygitsetinfo.sty is a derived work under the terms of the
% LPPL. It is based on version 1.0 of gitsetinfo.sty, available as part
% of the gitinfo package available from http://ctan.org/pkg/gitinfo.
%
% -----------------------------------------------------
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mygitsetinfo}[2014/04/09 v0.01 Auxiliary package for gitinfo]
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\RequirePackage{xstring}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{%
    family=gitinfo,
    prefix=gitInf@
    }
\DeclareStringOption{shash}
\DeclareStringOption{lhash}
\DeclareStringOption{authname}
\DeclareStringOption{authemail}
\DeclareStringOption{authsdate}
\DeclareStringOption{authidate}
\DeclareStringOption{authudate}
\DeclareStringOption{commname}
\DeclareStringOption{commemail}
\DeclareStringOption{commsdate}
\DeclareStringOption{commidate}
\DeclareStringOption{commudate}
\DeclareStringOption{refnames}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
\renewcommand{\gitAbbrevHash}{\gitInf@shash}
\renewcommand{\gitHash}{\gitInf@lhash}
\renewcommand{\gitAuthorName}{\gitInf@authname}
\renewcommand{\gitAuthorEmail}{\gitInf@authemail}
\renewcommand{\gitAuthorDate}{\gitInf@authsdate}
\renewcommand{\gitAuthorIsoDate}{\gitInf@authidate}
\renewcommand{\gitAuthorUnixDate}{\gitInf@authudate}
\renewcommand{\gitCommitterName}{\gitInf@commname}
\renewcommand{\gitCommitterEmail}{\gitInf@commemail}
\renewcommand{\gitCommitterDate}{\gitInf@commsdate}
\renewcommand{\gitCommitterIsoDate}{\gitInf@commidate}
\renewcommand{\gitCommitterUnixDate}{\gitInf@commudate}
\renewcommand{\gitReferences}{\gitInf@refnames}
\newcommand{\git@vtag}[1]{%
    \def\do##1{%
      \StrCut{##1}{: }\lcut\rcut%
      \IfDecimal\rcut{% case where we have string: decimal e.g. tag: 1.0
        \renewcommand{\gitVtag}{\rcut}
        \renewcommand{\gitVtags}{\space\rcut}
        \renewcommand{\gitVtagn}{\space\rcut}
        \listbreak
      }{%
        \IfDecimal{##1}{% case where we have decimal e.g. 1.0
          \renewcommand{\gitVtag}{##1}
          \renewcommand{\gitVtags}{\space##1}
          \renewcommand{\gitVtagn}{\space##1}
          \listbreak
        }{}%
      }%
    }%
    \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{#1}%
}%
\git@vtag{\gitInf@refnames}
```

The result does not look terribly impressive but I trust it is an improvement over '(None)'...

[image: Unimpressive looking result...]

This will also work with the case covered by the original `gitsetinfo`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gitinfo}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{gitHeadInfo.gin}
\usepackage[%
        refnames={ (HEAD, 1.0, master)}
     ]{mygitsetinfo}% call the new routine here
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\gitVtags
\gitVtag
\gitVtagn

\end{document}
```

[image: Identical looking result...]

Comment: Thanks, that works for my case. Can you explain a little what the various `cut` commands do? Ideally a solution would allow both `tag: 0.2` and `0.2` to work.

Comment: @Jörg See my edit. This should work OK for both cases. Also, I've added a bit of explanation. (Cat was sick last night when I was posting this so my original answer was not very informative!)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the code! Just out of interest, do you know why is it not possible just to issue `\newcommand{\git@vtag}...` before the `gitVtag`?

Comment: Thanks for your support! I may well 'steal' this code sometime, though of course, fully attributed either as "cfr from TeX/.SE" or something better if you email me.

Comment: @Jörg I'm not positive - Brent.Longborough would be in a better position to say for sure. But I think it is because when you load `gitsetinfo`, it probably reads in the file and parses it at that point. So renewing the command later is no good as the variables are all set by that point. At least, that is how it seemed to be working when I experimented and that's why I ended up with this solution - it was the only way my changes seemed to actually make any difference.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough That's fine. I'm glad you don't mind and hope it is useful. I can email you the details I put in packages I maintain so things are kept consistent. Thanks.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough Email sent. Let me know if you don't get it. (I'm not sure whether I correctly interpreted your email address from the package documentation.)

Comment: For those who are interested, I am currently working on gitinfo release 2.0, which will incorporate @cfr 's code. There will also be a new set of Release commands based on metadata from `git-describe`, and one or two other minor improvements. Email requests for '2.0-beta' will be promptly and happily replied to.

Comment: Oh, and @Jorg 's code, too!

Comment: @Brent.Longborough Maybe that comment should be tagged onto Jorg's code in the question?